# SDL_SetRenderTarget (SDL2)

Tags: c, sdl-2

I have two examples which should work equally in my opinion.
**But it works in one case and it does not in second case.**
I need to use second case in my code. I need to refer a texture adress 
to another function for allocate texture and make some changes on the texture and copy it to renderer.
But it does not work. Can anybody help with this. I am a beginner so I think it must be some elementary mistake. Thanks everybody who read this.

**Here there is my simplified code in two cases:**

**First case works:**

```
/*---------------------------------in main.c----------------------------*/

#include "global.h"

int main(/*...*/)
{
    create_txt_texture();
    to_screen(); /*Here there is red color on a screen*/

    return 0;
}

    /*-------------------------------in program.c-------------------------*/

#include "global.h"

int create_txt_texture()
{
    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, /*...*/);

    txt_to_bitmap();

    return 0;
}

void txt_to_bitmap()
{
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,0,0,255); 
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);  /*filling target with red color*/

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
}

void to_screen()
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); /*Here there is red color on a screen*/
}

    /*-------------------------------in global.h-------------------------*/

#ifndef __GLOBAL_H__
#define __GLOBAL_H__

SDL_Renderer *renderer;
SDL_Texture *texture;

void to_screen();
void txt_to_bitmap();
int create_txt_texture();

#endif
```

**Second case does not work:**

```
/*-------------------------------in main.c-------------------------------*/

#include "global.h"

int main(/*...*/)
{
    create_txt_texture(texture);
    to_screen(); /*Here there is not red color on a screen*/

    return 0;
}

    /*-------------------------------in program.c-------------------------*/

#include "global.h"

int create_txt_texture(SDL_Texture *final_texture)
{
    final_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, /*...*/);

    txt_to_bitmap(final_texture);

    return 0;
}

void txt_to_bitmap(SDL_Texture *final_texture)
{
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, final_texture);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,0,0,255); 
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);  /*filling target with red color*/

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
}

void to_screen()
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); /*Here there is not red color on a screen*/
}

    /*-------------------------------in global.h---------------------------*/

#ifndef __GLOBAL_H__
#define __GLOBAL_H__

SDL_Renderer *renderer;
SDL_Texture *texture;

void to_screen();
void txt_to_bitmap(SDL_Texture *final_texture);
int create_txt_texture(SDL_Texture *final_texture);

#endif
```

Comment: I can't, because I can't hit what is wrong. Only change I did is described above. In the second case everything is good but it will draw nothing on RenderTarget.

Comment: You *do* note that "one works, the other not". So you *do* see a difference, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    /*-------------------------------in main.c-------------------------------*/

#include "global.h"

int main(/*...*/)
{
    create_txt_texture(texture);
    to_screen(); /*Here there is not red color on a screen*/

    return 0;
}

    /*-------------------------------in program.c-------------------------*/

#include "global.h"

int create_txt_texture(SDL_Texture*& final_texture)
{
    final_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, /*...*/);

    txt_to_bitmap(final_texture);

    return 0;
}

void txt_to_bitmap(SDL_Texture *final_texture)
{
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, final_texture);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,0,0,255); 
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);  /*filling target with red color*/

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
}

void to_screen()
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); /*Here there is not red color on a screen*/
}

    /*-------------------------------in global.h---------------------------*/

#ifndef __GLOBAL_H__
#define __GLOBAL_H__

SDL_Renderer *renderer;
SDL_Texture *texture;

void to_screen();
void txt_to_bitmap(SDL_Texture*& final_texture);
int create_txt_texture(SDL_Texture *final_texture);

#endif
```

**Explanation:** You are passing Texture pointer by value not by reference which is causing this issue.
When you pass any thing by value another copy of that thing gets created, So in your case after passing pointer by value you have two pointers (texture and final_texture) pointed to the same location, but after the step

```
final_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, /*...*/);
```

your **final_texture** pointed to the newly allocated texture while your **texture** pointer remain unchanged. So to make **texture** pointer to also point to the newly created texture location you have to pass it as by reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Learner, you described problem perfectly. I changed  int create_txt_texture(SDL_Texture *final_texture) to        SDL_Texture * create_txt_texture(SDL_Texture *final_texture) for referencing new created texture. It works perfectly.

Comment: Since when does C support references? The question is tagged as C, not C++.

Comment: @jpw In C you can use double pointer to resolve this problem.. Thanks for pointing out..

Comment: There is the option in the top left at the starting of this answer. An empty tick is there below the big Zero, select that tick.

Comment: To jpw. Sorry for my bad English. I mean returning pointer in  SDL_Texture * create_txt_texture()